# How I can evaluate a scope object in an ng-Class directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a button, that when clicked, increments to the next indexed item in an array. When I reach the last item in the array, I want to add a class to the button tag called "endButton".

The way I intend to evaluate the expression involves just the html code where I think it's best to use the `ng-class` directive. I want to evaluate an expression, that when true, adds the "endButton" class.

I have tried the following syntax:

```
<button type="button" class="right-btn col-xs-6" role="menuitem" ng-click="clickNext()" ng-class="{'endButton' : scope.myArray.Index === 10}">Next</button>
```

This returns the scope object as a string value, so it doesn't work. I have included the double curly brackets around the `myArray.Index` but it yields a string as well.

Any idea how I can evaluate a scope object in an `ng-class` directive?

Answer (score 0):

any expression for an ng-directive is already in the context of the scope variable, you don't need to reference it. I'm not sure what $scope.myArray.Index is but I'm guessing it's the index that you're up to, so you should be able to just change it to myArray.Index == 10

```
<button type="button" class="right-btn col-xs-6" role="menuitem" ng-click="clickNext()" ng-class="{'endButton' : index === 10}">Next</button>
```

Here's a jsfiddle example, please note I haven't included the array

https://jsfiddle.net/e16v9avj/

Answer (score 0):

You're not too far off from what your looking for. I believe it's to with your parsing of integers and strings. Here's a working example

```css
.red { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-init="ctr=0">
  <p ng-class="{red: ctr===3}">{{ctr}}<p>
  <button ng-click="ctr=ctr+1">
    Click Me
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$last` instead of checking for *index*. See [**`JsFiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/p8ybr942/1/) and demo below using `ng-class="{'endButton' : $last}"`:

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
  {{index}}
  <div ng-repeat="element in array">
     <div>{{element}}</div>
     <button type="button" class="right-btn col-xs-6" role="menuitem"
         ng-click="clickNext()" ng-class="{'endButton' : $last}">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```